# How to get correct 'nameinlink' in 'cleveref' when using 'newtheoremstyle' and custom numbering for lemmas and similar environments?

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, cleveref, newtheorem

I am using slightly customized theorem styles and have defined the theorem environment to follow the section numbering and lemmas, propositions, and conjectures environments to follow the theorem numbering as shown in the minimal code example and in the picture below. My problem is that then `\cref` does not quote the correct environment name, but only 'Theorem' instead. My guess is that it has to do with the way I have set up the numbering for the additional theorem environments, but I don't know how to fix the issue.

Minimal code example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm} 

\newtheoremstyle{italic}{3pt}{3pt}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{:}{3pt}{}
\newtheoremstyle{normal}{3pt}{3pt}{}{}{\bfseries}{:}{3pt}{}

\theoremstyle{italic}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition} 
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{normal}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}

\usepackage[
bookmarksopen=false,
bookmarksnumbered,
colorlinks=true,
urlcolor=teal,
linkcolor=violet,
citecolor=green,
frenchlinks=false
]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref} % always after hyperref    
\usepackage{hypcap}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter1}
\section{Section1}
\begin{theorem}\label{abc}
$a + b = c$
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}\label{pqr}
$p+q+r=0$
\end{lemma}

\chapter{Chapter2}
\section{Section2}  
\cref{pqr} is not even wrong.       
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: example]

> But it should be: "**Lemma** 1.1.2 is not even wrong". How do I get the correct environment name using `\cref`?

Feel free to add more appropriate tags.